# OneSignal web view user based notification

Tags: android

I'm building a Webview (Android app) of a website that has register/login system.
Using OneSignal, now I need Android push notification to specific user that logged via the app.
Let's say:
User A has an account on www.mysite.com
The android app only loads www.mysite.com on a Webview
When User A logged in via the app, and do something, I need to send push notification to that user, to his android device
Does anyone know how to implement that?

Thank you.